# filezilla, error while writing failure

Tags: file-transfer, filezilla

I'm transferring a very large (35GB) file through SFTP and FileZilla.

Now the transfer is **59.7%** done, but I keep getting this error, and it hasn't changed that number for hours.

```
Error:     File transfer failed after transferring 1,048,576 bytes in 10 seconds
Status:    Starting upload of C:\Files\static.sql.gz
Status:    Retrieving directory listing...
Command:   ls
Status:    Listing directory /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs
Command:   reput "C:\Files\static.sql.gz" "static.sql.gz"
Status:    reput: restarting at file position 20450758656
Status:    local:C:\Files\static.sql.gz => remote:/var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/static.sql.gz
Error:     error while writing: failure
```

Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Is the remote volume out of free space?

Comment: Check disk space [here](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-check-disk-space-in-linux)

Answer (score 80):

[Credit to cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206707/filezilla-error-while-writing-failure#comment4549004_4206707): The remote volume was out of space.

Comment: This is huge... I was going out of my mind before I thought to contact the hardware department and see how much space they had reserved for the vm I was uploading to.

Comment: you're a livesaver

Comment: made my day! :D

Answer (score 16):

I encountered the same situation.
Go to your server, run "df" command to see if there is a problem of hard disk space.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Timeouts_on_large_files

Answer (score 2):

Recently faced this issue, Turned out to be the disk space issue. Removed some old logs, specially mysqld.log file which was in GBs. It worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

filezilla, **error while writing: failure** issue occurred when server storage is full. Login in Linux server and
Kindly run below two commands to find out which files are consuming max storage in /var/log recursively..

for MB Size:

```
sudo du -csh $(sudo find /var/log -type f) |grep M|sort -nr
```

For GB size:

```
sudo du -csh $(sudo find /var/log -type f) |grep G|sort -nr
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case it was because the file exceeded the user's quota. We use Virtualmin and the virtual server had a default quota of just 1GB. Increasing that value in Virtualmin solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I tried to replace the file which was already open or running in the background. Once closed, I was able to overwrite the file.