# Amazon EC2 error - received failure with description Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filezilla

I am unable to upload any files from FileZilla to my Amazon EC2 instance (running a m4.large instance). Its throwing the error " received failure with description 'Failure' ". Also noticed that my webapps which used to run on this instance are not working anymore.

I have enough disk space on this server; anyone can throw some light on why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experienced such error with any of my instances; however, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891231/5395709) that may help shed some light.

Also, have you tried uploading it with SCP? Try that and see if you receive the same error; I'm curious to know if this is related to SFTP and FileZilla.

`scp local_file user@remote_host:remote_file`

If you're using an SSH key to authenticate on the instance, you'll need to use the `-i` argument along with the key name.

`scp -i pem_file_name local_file user@remote_host:remote_file`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any feedbacks for this answer

Comment: I encountered the same error and it is due to the server running out of space. I found the solution at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206707/filezilla-error-while-writing-failure#comment4549004_4206707)